# Why is the division by zero not caught in a generic catch()

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following code which should throw a division by zero exception while running. It seems that the exception is not be caught at all. I am using catch(...) to catch any exception from the try block. Is catch(...) a good approach to catch any exceptions from the try block??

```
try
{
    printf("Try Block");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", 1 / i);
    }       
}

catch (...)
{
    printf("Division by zero");
}
```

Comment: No, it should not necessarily throw. If it does, that's due to the undefined behaviour, and catching it and continuing on will likely bring only pain.

Comment: Division by zero is not a standard C++ exception.

Comment: This was just an example to catch any exceptions within the try block.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on the behaviour of division by zero; it's undefined:

**N4296 §5/4:**

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure an exception is thrown when you try to divide by zero, you'll have to make your own wrapper that does it:

```
long double Divide(long double numerator, long double denominator)
{
  if (denominator == 0)
  {
    throw std::range_error("Division by zero!");
  }
  return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want portable code that handles divide by zero by throwing an exception, then you could write a class that wraps a suitable numeric type and checks before divide and mod operations, and use it instead of the inbuilt numeric types....  The C++ library does not provide such a type.  In reality, it's not particularly useful - you can just check in your code in the specific places that might do a division or mod operation with 0.